# Check if a record was added in a month

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

Currenty this is my code but how do i iterate through the month until the client finishes payments

```
$line4 = mysql_query("SELECT DAY(paydate) AS PayDay,clientid
FROM transactions
where transactions.clientid=client.clientid AND transactions.product=invoices.product AND
      DAY(transactions.paydate)> 10 and YEAR(transactions.paydate) = 2012 AND 
      MONTH(transactions.paydate) = 3 AND transactions.balance > 0
order by client.clientid");
```

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What does "terate through the month until the client finishes payments" really mean?

Comment: Surely the results from that query 'are' the payments.  So you need only fetch them.